# What's the easiest way to parse multi-line SQL statements in Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm pretty new to Java, but I'm looking for Java code that can take multi-line SQL statements, say something like this from a flat file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REQ.TR_INPT_STAY_DETAI_SQ_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON REQ.INPT_STAY_DETAIL
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT REQ.SQ_INPT_DETAIL.nextval INTO :new.INPT_STAY_DETAIL_PID from DUAL;
END;
```

And convert those multi-line statements into one line SQL statements like this (maybe wrapped in this display), to be executed as a single JDBC statement against an Oracle database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REQ.TR_INPT_STAY_DETAI_SQ_BI BEFORE INSERT ON REQ.INPT_STAY_DETAIL FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT REQ.SQ_INPT_DETAIL.nextval INTO :new.INPT_STAY_DETAIL_PID from DUAL; END;
```

I've tried to do this with multiple BufferedReaders, and/or using the mark() method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The trouble seems to be the semi-colon at both the end of the long statement, and with the END; statement.

Your thoughts on the easiest way to do this?

---

I think I made some progress, but if the same SQL input file also has simpler SQL commands, like:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE.NAME_HERE;
```

They'll fail on my first condition here:

```
if ( !thisLine.startsWith("END;") && !thisLine.equals("/") ) {
    sqlBuf.append(thisLine).append(" ");
    statementReady = false;
}
else if (thisLine.startsWith("END;")) {
    sqlBuf.append(thisLine).append(" ");
    statementReady = true;
}
else if (thisLine.equals("/")) {
    statementReady = true;
}
else { }
```

I check the statemendReady variable later on before I run the .execute.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried to use unsuccessfully?

Comment: It's like 200 lines or so of horrible Java.  Is that OK?

Comment: that might be a bit much.  just show the snippets where you are actually reading and concatenating the data

Comment: If you have a file full of sql commands, and you need to process them one at a time, that is a very different problem.  You may want to clarify what commands are in this file and how general a solution you need.

Comment: I guess I figured the multi-line statements would be the harder ones to figure out, and the 1-liners would be easy...  The SQL file might contain trigger definitions with the END; and /, and it might also have simple statements, like above.  Either of those could be on 1 line, or on multiple lines.  I'm not sure if I can strictly enforce the format of the file that's given to me.  I was hoping I could handle any format, but I guess that's the crux of the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Just read in each line, and append them using StringBuilder, but, don't append any line that has `End;` as you won't need that for your query.

You should also ignore `Go` if the file has that.

Then you can just turn the StringBuilder into a String and you have it.

Just remember to put a space between each line.

For more on reading several lines from a file you can look at:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml

The important part is:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
       if (!strLine.startsWith("End"))
          buf.append(strLine).append(" ");
    }
```

Comment: +1 - rziegler72, I strongly recommend this approach ( I was about to do the same) as it works well and very efficiently.  Since your new to Java make sure you close any writers or readers.

Comment: +1 - This should work but don't remove the 'END;' line.  The line is needed if there is a 'BEGIN' line. The equivalent of GO in Oracle is a line with a single '/', this will have to be removed if it is present.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try something like this & see where I get.  ANTLR seems a bit above my head at this point.

Comment: @Vincent - I didn't know, obviously, that sending the 'End;' would be important. I have been too long on SQL Server (hence the 'GO').

Comment: I edited my question above to show what I tried, so it's getting closer, but still not catching every case...

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use ANTLR. It has [oracle SQL grammer](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) which will certainly help with many corner cases around the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pre-process the file so that you don't have as many newlines by doing using a search and replace on the newline character and add newlines at the end of statements, then each line you read will be a single sql statement?

(Unix tools like `sed` can make this very easy)

Otherwise, James is right (just beat me to it).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of Oracle SQL statement is quite complicated, you can't get SQL statement or PLSQL stored procedure from a script file easily with this string match algorithm. What you need is a fully working SQL Parser which can parse the whole SQL script correctly, Here is [an article](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/visit-sql-statement-recursively/) shows you how to do this with the help of [general sql parser](http://www.sqlparser.com).